# How to remove ALERT - ONE OF YOUR APPS NEEDS ATTENTION notice?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app publish to CHPLAY. After update the app that app have been reject and now I unpublished this app.

However, the notice still show at top of my chplay. I want to remove it. Please help me.

Comment: they already send you details mail regrading this

Comment: There is no way that you can remove app from developer console once it is created

Comment: yes, i want hide the notice becase I unpublish the app have been reject but I don't see hide button

Comment: hi, did you have solution for this case ?